# split hostname and domain name from fqdn using regex

Tags: java, regex

I am working on regular expression. i.e java.google.com here "java" is hostname and "google.com" is domain name. Now I would like to extract from

```
String fqdn = "java.google.com";

String hostname = "java";
String domain = "google.com";
```

using regex.

I tried like this

```
String text = "java.google.com";
String extensionRemoved = text.split("\\.")[0];
```

I am getting result as java. But I want some regex which should give me "java" separate string and "google.com" separate String.

I can use StringTokenizer but I don't want to use StringTokenizer as it effect performance If I have 1000,1,00,000 records from db. Thanks if any one gives efficient solution for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this kind of simple parsing, `indexOf` and `substring` will be more efficient.

**edit**
But if you really want a regex then this one is basic but do it ˋ(\w+).([.\w]+)ˋ the ˋgroup(1)`contains the hostname and ˋgroup(2)` the domain. But some edge cases may not match.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
String text = "java.google.com";
String domain = text.split("\\.")[0];
String ext = text.replace(domain, "");
System.out.print("Domain:"+domain);
System.out.print("\n");
System.out.print("Ext:"+ext);
```

Answer (score 2):

Note `String.split` has a variant that allows you to specify a maximum number of splits:

```
String[] x = "java.sun.com".split("\\.", 2);
System.out.println(x[0]); // java
System.out.println(x[1]); // sun.com
```